# What is Vulnerabilities in TestNG dependency? How that will impact the framework in terms of security?

Tags: java, selenium, dependencies, testng, ui-automation

Is it safe to use TestNG that has vulnerabilities? Because i haven't seen them earlier for the same version and could see now for same TestNG version?

JUNIT has no vulnerabilities. If TestNg has some vulnerability that could lead to security related issues, can i avoid using TestNG and can opt to use JUNIT?

[image]

Comment: of course you can.... you don't need TestNG to run jUnit.  Selenium also has significant security implications, so it's good to study up on all the ways you could expose yourself or your organization.

Comment: Thanks pcalkins. But my question also was - it is good to use TestNG with the vulnerabilities listed (refer screenshot from original ticket) or it is MUST to shift to Junit.

Comment: that's up to you.  You should research each one.  Zip/Tar files during ant process being one of them... consider whether you also need to evaluate all dependencies especially if using package managers.  Some more sophisticated attackers have been injecting code into widely used programs.  For instance the attack on "Solar Winds".  One of the cve's you listed was pretty old and was jUnit related.  The much bigger issue is really Selenium itself and how you secure credentials used in scripts and grid if you use one.

Comment: For instance, I see a LOT of posts here which include an option for configuring the driver of "no sandbox".  This is particularly dangerous if visiting sites you do not directly control.  Even without that flag, injections into your code could be possible and that code sits outside of the sandbox.  (Pretty much all of Selenium's vulnerabilities would be null if visiting a site you have control of... though grid would require a lot of protections since it's pretty open by default.)  Security is an endless road just as testing is.  You have to decide how secure is OK for you.

Comment: For specific info about CVE's and mitigations you should probably make a post at Security Exchange: https://security.stackexchange.com/